# Unbind all events but not those who already have an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is kind of tricky and I hope it's something that can be done. Basically what I am trying to achieve is this: If anyone clicks on the page or on any button, it needs to call a function. However, it only needs to call that function ONCE. After the event has been fired it should unbind that same event, but **it should also keep all the other events on the page**.

https://jsfiddle.net/1wrmqbb0/

```
$("body, body *").on("click keyup change", function() {
    console.log("CLICKED ONCE");
    $(this).unbind("click keyup change");
});
```

When the body or any other element in the body has been clicked, it should call the function/console.log or anything like that. Once it has done that, it should unbind them all again, because I only want this to happen once.

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    console.log("BUTTON HAS BEEN CLICKED");
});
```

However, when I do the above, it will unbind all the children of `<body>`, which means the `on("click")` from my button will be unbinded as well.

How do I keep my button from getting unbinded? **Note: I have a lot of elements, a lot of click handlers, and so on. I do not want to list each and every one of them or bind them all again afterwards**. It would be extremely nice to do something like this:

```
var firstTimeOnly = $("body, body *").on("click keyup change"....;
firstTimeOnly.not(":those-who-has-an-event-already").unbind("all");
```

(Yeah, I know that would be an awesome selector)

Comment: [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)?

Comment: @Teemu Basically yes, but it doesn't remove *all* the event handlers. If I apply them to `body *` each element still has the event until all are clicked/triggered/fired.

Comment: Then attach the events to `body` only, and remove them in the handler. Evenst bubble up to `body` from its child elements. Use a named function to remove the exact event.

Comment: @Teemu If I only apply the event to body, it will not fire if I click on a button, some text, or anything like that.

Comment: @Teemu Let me correct that: Yes, just setting it to `body` seems to work. Great. Thanks :)